# Will not download all songs from Itunes to Ipod classic

Tags: ipod

My OS is Windows 10. Itunes version is 12.12.6.1   My 80GB Ipod Classic software version is 1.1.2

I have over 2000 songs in my Icloud, (Itunes) and it only syncs 540 songs to my Ipod. I reset my Ipod, and removed and re-installed Itunes in Windows. I understand Apple no longer supports Ipod classics and deemed them obsolete. With that said do I need to upgrade to a newer version Ipod ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are these Apple Music (subscription) songs? If so, they can't be used on iPods, as they don't support the file format/DRM.

Comment: No, these are not "Apple Music" songs.... Songs purchased through Itunes, uploaded from from CD's  in Itunes

Comment: do you have it set to sync only checked songs, or to "manually manage"? Can you play the music files just fine on iTunes (not corrupted or missing)?

Comment: Set at Sync only to checked songs... Music files play just fine in Itunes